# Заставить работать скрипт только внутри нужного блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется блок, внутри которого при нажатии на кнопку `.color-pick__btn`, на картинке с таким же `data-number`, должен присваиваться класс `"active"`

```js
$(".color-pick__btn").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    return false;
  } else {

    $(".color-pick__btn", ).removeClass("active");
    $('.item-picture img', this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.item-picture img[data-number="' + $(this).attr('data-number') + '"]').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-slide">
  <div class="item-picture">
    <img src="https://d.neoldu.com/gallery/2153_2.jpg" alt="" class="active" data-number="4">

    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/09/03/46/alberta-2297204_640.jpg" alt="" data-number="5">
  </div>
  <div class="color-pick">
    <p>Bistfor</p>
    <div class="color-button">
      <div class="color-pick__btn active" data-number="4"></div>
      <div class="color-pick__btn" data-number="5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

вот скрипт, который отлично справляется, если блок `.item-slide` на странице один.

Но если таких блоков несколько, `class="active"` убирается везде, во всех блоках.
Не понимаю, как сделать так, чтоб действие выполнялось только внутри блока, на кнопку внутри которого идет клик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо использовать `$(this).closest(".item-slide")`, это найдёт текущий, ближайший `item-slide`  и остальных детей искать уже от него.

```
var itemSlide = $(this).closest(".item-slide")

itemSlide.find(".color-pick__btn").removeClass("active");
// ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @VladislavKovaliov если вам помогло отметьте пожалуйста ответ как ответ, и буду благодарен за лайк.

Comment: пока не могу ставить лайки